# Find ListBox from clicking on specific element in listbox item

Tags: wpf, listbox

I have created a control template for my ListBoxItem in a Listbox, and each ListBoxItem consist of the contentpresenter and a Image.

My question to you is... How can I find out, which listbox i clicked when I click my Image in the listBox item.

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemWithDelete" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Border Name="Border" Padding="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <Grid>
                                <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                <Image Name="ImageListItemDelete" Source="../Resources/Images/actions-delete-big-1.png" Width="20" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemIcon}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                               MouseLeftButtonUp="ImageListItemDelete_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundBrush}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

private void ImageListItemDelete_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  //Object sender is my Image i Clicked.
  if (ListBoxName.SelectedItem != null)
  {
    ListBoxName.Items.Remove(ListBoxName.SelectedItem);
  }
}
```

I want to replace ListBoxName with the listbox that contains this image i clicked, right now "ListBoxName" is hardcoded.

I know how to work down through listboxitems finding their content template, however I don't know how to work the reverse way. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to find the ancestor of a `UIElement` of a particular type is to use the [`VisualTreeHelper` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper(v=vs.110).aspx). From the linked page:

> Provides utility methods that perform common tasks involving nodes in a visual tree.

You can use this helper method to find your `ListBox`:

```
public T GetParentOfType<T>(DependencyObject element) where T : DependencyObject
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    if (element == null) return null;
    DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element);
    if (parent == null && ((FrameworkElement)element).Parent is DependencyObject) 
        parent = ((FrameworkElement)element).Parent;
    if (parent == null) return null;
    else if (parent.GetType() == type || parent.GetType().IsSubclassOf(type)) 
        return parent as T;
    return GetParentOfType<T>(parent);
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
ListBox listBox = GetParentOfType<ListBox>(sender as UIElement);
```

Comment: Thanks.. This was exactly what I was looking for. I knew the other one which traversed downwards through the child elements.

Answer (score 1):

you've got an answer however it may not always be the case due to template differences, so finding via Visual Tree or Logical tree would be appropriate

example

```
public static T FindAncestor<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : class
{
    DependencyObject target = dependencyObject;
    do
    {
        target = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(target);
    }
    while (target != null && !(target is T));
    return target as T;
}
```

usage

```
ListBox listBox = FindAncestor<ListBox>(sender as DependencyObject);
```

more sophisticated example here [Finding an ancestor of a WPF dependency object](http://www.hardcodet.net/2008/02/find-wpf-parent)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i was actually looking for something like this rather than my own example.